# Problem with pooled gradients for class activation map (CAM)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm using Keras to create gradient class activation maps to visualize my predictions, but for some of the images that I pass through, it returns zeros for the mean intensity of the gradient over a specific feature map channel. I'm using DenseNet121 to classify between two classes.
I've followed the guide that Francois Chollet wrote to use Grad Cams in his book Deep Learning with Python, and I also had the exact same issue with the VGG16 model as well, so I'm assuming that this is unrelated to the model I choose.

My model is as follows:

```
K.set_image_dim_ordering('tf')

dnet = DenseNet121(include_top=True, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(img_size, img_size, 3))
dnet.trainable=True
x = dnet.output
x = layers.Dense(100, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.4)(x)
x = layers.Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(input=dnet.input, output=x)

optimizer = Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, decay=0.08) 
class_weight = {0:cwr, 1:1}

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
model_hist = model.fit_generator(train, steps_per_epoch = 60, epochs = 2, class_weight = class_weight)
```

The code for the Grad CAM and associated heatmap:

```
img = load_img(load_path, target_size=(img_size, img_size))
img_tensor = img_to_array(img)
img_tensor = np.expand_dims(img_tensor, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(img_tensor)
preds = model.predict(x)
t = np.argmax(preds[0])
img = cv2.imread(str(load_path))

llayer = model.output[:,t]
last_conv_layer = model.get_layer(conv)
grads = K.gradients(llayer, last_conv_layer.output)[0]
pooled_grads = K.mean(grads, axis=(0, 1, 2))
iterate = K.function([model.input],[pooled_grads, last_conv_layer.output[0]])
pooled_grads_value, conv_layer_output_value = iterate([img_tensor])
for i in range(len(pooled_grads_value)):
    conv_layer_output_value[:, :, i] *= pooled_grads_value[i]


heatmap = np.mean(conv_layer_output_value, axis=-1)
heatmap = np.maximum(heatmap, 0)
heatmap /= (np.max(heatmap))
heatmap = cv2.resize(heatmap, (img.shape[1], img.shape[0]))
heatmap = np.uint8(255 * heatmap)
heatmap = cv2.applyColorMap(heatmap, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
cv2.imwrite('colormap.jpg', heatmap)
colormap = cv2.imread('colormap.jpg')
```

I localized the issue as far as I could to the pooled_grads_value. Printing this value gives

```
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

Also returns the following error when trying to plot the associated heatmap

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:85: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
```

An example of an image that works properly will return the pooled_grads_value as something similar

```
[ 3.52818736e-16 -2.74286623e-17 -1.04039105e-16  2.26564966e-15
  3.80025990e-16 -4.65492462e-16 -3.13070048e-16 -3.99670802e-16
 -4.33913274e-16 -1.11373781e-16 -2.18853726e-16 -3.50514463e-16
  1.03881816e-17 -6.30468010e-16 -5.57306545e-16 -1.23719115e-16
 -3.93387115e-17  7.59074981e-16 -5.14396333e-16 -1.02742529e-16
 -2.16168923e-16  1.81140590e-16 -6.42374594e-16  3.01582507e-17
 -5.55568844e-17 -3.05854862e-16  3.26082836e-17  2.35498082e-16
  7.86424100e-18  6.45698563e-16 -1.54681729e-16  1.11217808e-16]
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with the VGG16 model as base for my custom model, also getting the aforementioned `RuntimeWarning`. Did you manage to solve this in the meantime?